# AngularJs - Opening a Bootstrap dropdown menu on page load by programmatically triggering the "click" event (NO jQuery)

Tags: angularjs

May I ask if it's possible to trigger the click event of a dropdown menu programmatically on page load using AngularJS?

What I want to happen is that after loading the page, my navigation menu gets displayed automatically.

This is what I have so far:

```
<li class="menu-item" style="margin-top:15px">

<!-- Single button -->
    <div class="btn-group open" uib-dropdown is-open="status.isopen">

        <!-- Hamburger menu -->

        <img ng-init="displayMainMenu()" id="nav-burger" uib-dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled" ng-click="sMainMenu=true; isSubMenu=resetMenu(); getLinks(); bStopPropagation=true;" src="img/burger.png">

        <!-- Main menu -->
        <ul uib-dropdown-menu role="menu" aria-labelledby="single-button" ng-click="bStopPropagation && $event.stopPropagation()">

        <!-- Main Menu -->
        <li role="menuitem" class="main-menu-item" ng-repeat="link in links" ng-click="whatMenu(link.name); isSubMenu=false;" ng-show="isMainMenu">
        <img id="{{link.icon}}">{{link.name}}<img class="navi-expand-icon">
        </li>
        <!-- End Main Menu -->

        </ul>

     </div>
</li>
```

And this is my Angular JS code:

```
$scope.displayMainMenu = function () {
    var domElement = document.getElementById('nav-burger');

    alert('before timeout');   // <-- This gets triggered

    $timeout(function () {
        angular.element(domElement).triggerHandler('click');
    }, 0);

    alert('after timeout');    // <-- This doesn't get triggered...
}
```

I have a feeling that I'm really close, however I couldn't figure out why it's not working.

Thank you in advance for your replies.

Comment: Is $timeout declared and did you include it in your project? Did you get any console errors?

Comment: 1. No I haven't...I only got that from another question here in SO. Where should I ideally declare $timeout?

2. "TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'done'". I don't know what this means...

Answer (score 0):

The ng-click on your image triggers this:  **`ng-click="sMainMenu=true;"`**
However, to show your list items you have used **isMainMenu** `ng-show="isMainMenu"`

So I guess you made a typo.

Comment: Nope, it's not a typo. The reason behind that is the way the menu is supposed to be displayed. Once the user clicks on one of the items in the main menu, a submenu will show up and will overlap the main menu area instead of its default behavior (appearing on the right side). We need the isMainMenu to figure out which one of the menus is currently displayed.

I hope that made sense... :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the clue Matheno! I did some more research about $timeout and finally got it to work by declaring $timeout in the controller:

```
app.controller('ctrlDropdown', function ($scope, $timeout) {

    $scope.isMainMenu = true;
    $scope.isSubMenu = false;
    $scope.links = "";
    $scope.subLinks = "";
    $scope.selectedLink = "";
    $scope.bStopPropagation = true;

   ...
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help.